# Excel Nested If statement with COUNTIF and ISBLANK

Tags: database, excel, if-statement

I am writing a code that pulls on information from a database. I am checking if A1 is in the database between D2 to W2 and if G3 is blank. If both of those things are true then return E3. If just the first part is true (A1 is in the database) then return "something else". If neither of those things are true, then return nothing.

Here is the code I have written:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Database!D2:W2, $A$1)), IF(ISBLANK(G3)), "", E3), "something else"))
```

I am getting an error with this formula but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Too many `)` see `=IF(COUNTIF(Database!D2:W2, $A$1), IF(ISBLANK(G3), "", E3), "something else")`

Comment: Wow, dont know how I missed that. Thanks! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

=IF(AND(COUNTIF(Database!D2:W2, $A$1)>0,(ISBLANK(G3)),E3,
IF(COUNTIF(Database!D2:W2, $A$1)>0,"something else","Neither"))